# Why .live() works, but not .on()?

Tags: jquery

In jquery1.71, .live() is deprecated. Nevertheless, it still works

```
var toggleBtn = document.createElement('input');
toggleBtn.id = 'toggleBtn';
toggleBtn.type = 'button';
toggleBtn.value = 'Close';
box.appendChild(toggleBtn);

$('#toggleBtn').live('click', function() {
   alert("hihi");            
});
```

I tried the recommended .on(). Strangely, this fails

```
var toggleBtn = document.createElement('input');
toggleBtn.id = 'toggleBtn';
toggleBtn.type = 'button';
toggleBtn.value = 'Close';
box.appendChild(toggleBtn);

$('#toggleBtn').on('click', function() {
   alert("hihi");            
});
```

Comment: Deprecated doesn't mean "removed" or "dysfunctional". It's "don't use this, because it will be removed at some point in the future".

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, `on` works totally fine: http://jsfiddle.net/twawk/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you read the documentation fully.  For `.on()` to work like `.live()` (or `.delegate()`) the second argument must be the selector to delegate to.

```
$(document).on('click', '#toggleBtn', function () {});
```

You can use a more specific selector, of course.

Comment: It works! Thanks, I will read the documentation first before posting next time

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me, here's a jsFiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/CC3Ze/

Firefox 11.0 on Ubuntu 11.10.